# Android DDMS does not list apps running on device

Tags: android, emulation, ddms, jdb

Running DDMS to the **emulator** allows me to view all currently-running apps and their respective port number which I can then use on JDB.

DDMS to an **actual device** does list the device in the DDMS window, but I cannot expand it to show all currently-running apps.

AKA, all apps on the emulator are debug-able but not those on the device.

Am I doing something wrong on the device?

Comment: You are not doing any thing wrong :) but you have not permission to see that section on real device, until you have a rooted device.

Comment: I see! Can't believe I didn't think of that, since this device is new to me. I'll root and see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Rooting the phone immediately works.

Credits to Pankaj Kumar for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Simpy rooting my device does not work in my case.

If you only want to show information of your app, adding *"android:debuggable="true"* in your the corresponding Manifest.xml.

Otherwise, rooting the device and flashing a customized boot.img with "ro.debuggable" set to 1.

Why? Check out:
[ro.debuggable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143960/androidstudio-what-does-debuggable-do)